# conda install コマンドを実行すると SSLError が表示される

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, conda

下記のようなエラーが出てしまい、原因がわかりません。conda installをしようとすると毎回同じようなエラーが出てしまいます。webサイトで調べてみましたが、自分の知識が足りず解決できませんでした。

anacondaやpython環境の構築に関して詳しい方、ご回答をお願いします。

原因の心当たりがあるとすれば、先日macOSを最新版をインストールしたことです。

```
conda update --all

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/main/osx-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, \'Unexpected EOF\')")))'))
```

動作環境は下記です。

ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.15.1
BuildVersion:   19B88

Comment: 接続しているネットワークはプロキシを経由する必要があったりしませんか？ (学校や職場のネットワークでプロキシ経由のログインが必要など)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！家のwifiや携帯会社のテザリング機能でネットワークを利用しています。プロキシについて詳しくは知りませんが、調べたところ経由していないと思われます。

Comment: いろいろいじった結果治りました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 試行錯誤した過程や結果を個別の「回答」としてまとめてもらうと、同じ問題に遭遇したユーザの助けになると思いますので検討してみてください (ここでは 自己回答 も歓迎されます)。

Comment: わかりました！アドバイスありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決いたしました。

どの操作が解決に至ったものだったのかわかりませんが、おそらく何らかの操作でconda init のコマンドで行われるはずの処理が初期化されてしまってたことが原因でした。conda init を打つことで解消できました。